# What are the most important Java libraries?

Tags: java

I've read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450906/important-frameworks-tools-to-learn)  on Stackoverflow, but it's been over two years since it was asked. I am a beginning Java programmer and have little knowledge of appreciated and widely-used libraries for this platform.

Of course I do use *some* libraries (JUnit, parts of Spring), but I'd love to have a list of libraries, that every Java developer should know (i.e. Hibernate, Velocity..?). I am interested in every field of Java applications.

What would you recommend for me (or any other beginner) to check out?

Comment: would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035445/what-are-the-most-important-things-to-learn-about-java-programming) help?

Comment: Too many to list. Much of Apache Commons. Guava. Any number of templating engines. So much of this depends on what you actually care about--"every field of Java application" is a laughably-wide scope.

Comment: That's true, but it's easy to notice, that MVC is more general than implementations of JSR 1234, that nobody has heard of ; o

Comment: The most important Java libraries are the ones you need to write your application.

Comment: While beautifully stated, your answer is not too helpful.. :-(

Comment: Lately I was working on gathering some data and preparing answer to this question http://www.77dev.com/2014/05/what-are-most-popular-java-libraries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good list of Java libraries you should know about.

https://java-source.net/

Answer (score 2):

Every beginner should spend more time learning core java. There are no all-around libraries. Most if not all  libraries are problem/domain specific...

My oppinion...

Comment: this must be comment not an answer , although i like you oppinion

Answer (score 1):

**Apache commons** has many libraries (like copying a stream to another). In the Java EE web application area the **Spring framework** provided independent utility libraries (like file upload servlet filter and for dependency injection), that meanwhile becomes less important because of the simplifications in Java EE.